# Максимальное подмножество попарно не связанных друг с другом окружностей

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Здравствуйте, есть вот такая задача:
На плоскости задано множество окружностей. Две окружности A и B назовём связанными,
если они пересекаются либо существует третья окружность C заданного множества,
связанная с A и B. Выбрать максимальное подмножество попарно не связанных друг с
другом окружностей.

Сначала я строю что-то типа матрицы смежности, в которой a[i][j]=1, если i-я и j-я окружности связанны, остальные элементы равны нулю.

```
int** CreateAdjacencyMatrix(std::vector<Circle>& circleCollection) {
    int size = circleCollection.size();
    int** adjMatrix = new int*[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        adjMatrix[i] = new int[size];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            //Если окружности пересекаются
            if(CircleCross(circleCollection[i], circleCollection[j])){
                adjMatrix[i][j]=adjMatrix[j][i]=1;
            }else adjMatrix[i][j]=adjMatrix[j][i]=0;
         //Ищем смежную окружность, которая пересекается с 2мя текущими
        for(int k=0; k<size; k++){
            if(k==i||k==j)continue;

            if(CircleCross(circleCollection[i],    circleCollection[k])&&CircleCross(circleCollection[j], circleCollection[k]))
                adjMatrix[i][j]=adjMatrix[j][i]=1;
            }
        }
    }
    return adjMatrix;
}
```

Вот только дальше я понятия не имею что нужно сделать, что бы найти наибольшее множество несвязанных окружностей. Подскажите пожалуйста, как дальше поступить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение состоит в том, чтобы удалять из множества все связанные окружности до тех пор, пока не останутся только несвязанные. По сути имеет место граф, а ваша задача является задачей поиска наибольшего внутреннего устойчивого подмножества (МВУП).

Comment: То есть, я неправильно решаю задачу? Мне же нужны не просто несвязанные окружности, а попарно несвязанные

Comment: Вы построили не "что-то типа матрицы смежности", а именно матрицу смежности. Она задает граф. МВУП этого графа и есть "максимальное подмножество попарно не связанных друг с другом окружностей". Вас интересовало, что делать, после того как матрица смежности построена. Я рекомендую почитать про алгоритмы поиска МВУП, там описаны все недостающие детали.

Comment: Из алгоритмов, нашёл только алгоритм Магу, но он вроде как для ориентированного графа. А у меня неориентированный

Comment: Например, http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9A%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B0
Раздел "Нахождение максимальных (по включению) независимых множеств вершин" про ваш случай.

Comment: Не совсем понял, как реализовать алгоритм, у вас реализации не найдётся?